# VS tells me to add a reference to an seemingly unrelated assembly. How to find out why?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I created a new unit test project to test my NHibernate mappings.
The NHibernate mappings are in a project that also contains EF entities.
In my unit test I only use types that don't even have an indirect reference to the Entity Framework, but still, when I compile the unit test project, I get the following error:

> The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Is there any way to find out, why this reference is needed? I already checked all used classes multiple times and couldn't find anything...

I have the feeling I am missing something here...

Comment: If NHibernate includes mappings to a project that contain EF entities, then System.Data.Entity would be a required reference.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't understand your comment. Could you please clarify? NHibernate doesn't include any mappings as I use the default build of NHibernate from the website...

Comment: And if you give an answer use the answer method instead of commenting :).

Comment: AFAIK this is a must rule to reference dependencies of the assemblies which referenced by a given project.

Comment: @sll: No, it is not. You need to add a reference to that other assembly only if you use types that need the other assembly. Sample: Project `A` references `B`. `B` has two classes: `B1` and `B2`. `B1` has a method that returns a string and `B2` has a method that returns `C1`. `C1` is defined in assembly `C` which is referenced only by `B` but not by `A`. If `A` now only uses `B1` there is no need to reference `C` in `A`. Even if I use `B2` in `A` there is no need to reference `C` unless I use the method that returns `C1`.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you using? I mean Full version or Client Profile? Found in intrawebs that some DLLs are not a part of Client Profile and this is whey they should be referenced explicitly

Comment: @sll: Good idea, but that's not the problem here. But anyhow, I checked and everything is using the full profile.

Comment: Isn't it Code Analysis that is complaining?

Comment: Why do you think it is code analysis?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I got more of an "assembly could not be found for analysis" warning. Definitely not a compiler error.

Comment: It was kind of a long shot that maybe Code Analysis wasn't able to find the referenced assemblies for analysis. But then I saw you get compiler errors and that is mostly not the case with CodeAnalysis. When you double-click on the message it should take you to the location where the error occurs.

Comment: @riezebosch: Yes, it takes me to a location but it seems random. That line doesn't use any type that has anything to do with EF. If I comment that line, the error message pops up at another line...

Comment: It could very well be unrelated, but I have run into a similar error when compiling a wpf user control. The xaml parser decided it needed an assembly containing a base class or i/f at compile time. Maybe something similar is going on here. I can post moredetailed info ifyou like.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party on this one, but I had a situation once where the xml comments for one class referenced a class in an assembly that my project didn't reference.  It caused intermittent errors since it only tried to reference the assembly when the xml comment was loaded.

Comment: @mydogisbox: Good idea, but there is not a single comment in the project :-)

Comment: Yeah, didn't think that was the issue, but thought I would throw it out there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DLL inspection tool (like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (freee!), or [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)) and have a look inside your test-referenced DLLs.  You'll spot the one with the Using statement quite quickly, hopefully, and get a clearer picture of what's happening.

As has been said, double-clicking will pull up the error location but only if it's in code you've written, third party DLLs naturally won't play ball.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You are sure that you don't use types inheriting or implementing any of the types in System.Data.Entity, this could be buried deep in the inheritance chain, like the use of a method returning a object defined in your DAL which either directly implements IEntityWithRelationships or gets the implementation from a base class also defined in your DAL, that would conceal the use of System.Data.Entity from your test assembly when you try to find references as it would show up as being used by an entity in your DAL instead... (Depending on what feature you are using to determine this, I am just guessing something like "Find Usages")

E.g. in your A, B, C example... if say A uses a B3 class that inherits from C2. When searching for usages on C2 you would only find B3 and not A. But because A uses B3 which inherits C2, A requires a reference to C

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Pistachio](http://www.granthinkson.com/2007/11/08/announcing-pistachio-wpf-resource-visualizer/). It is made to load in a .csproj, then find all the resources in the project and where they are used. Might be worth a shot to find out where that DLL is needed.

Comment: I used Resharpers similar feature and it said that `System.Data.Entity` is not used by any of my code in the unit testing project.

Comment: BTW: Pistachio isn't working, most likely because I am using VS2010.

Comment: Ah true, sorry. Haven't used for a VS2010 project yet, was unaware it wasn't updated.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth : What version of ReSharper are you using, 6.0?... are you then using the "Find Usages" or "Find Code Dependant on Module" feature???... Find usages will only show direct dependencies, the other will show indirect dependencies as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://checkasm.booring.net/ CheckAsm tool. Load all your assemblies that you refer directly in your project and find out which one is using the missing reference. From there you need to ask the provider of that reference why they needed that assembly.

Hope that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not what I am asking. My unit test project references my DAL project which references System.Data.Entity. So I know which of my references references this assembly. But I still don't know why I should reference it in my unit test project, too. See my long comment to my question. This explains why my unit test project shouldn't need a reference although the referenced project has a reference to that assembly.

Comment: Ahh I see, you're right, interesting. I'm trying to replicate the issue but no luck so far. It might be related to your project properties.

Comment: Could it be something related to version of .NET, I don't know how but only clue I can see, that you're using .NET 2010 but using 3.5 version of System.Data.Entity. In normal circumstances it should have been 4.0 of course unless you changed it to 3.5 intentionally to support old version.

Comment: My projects are still all on .NET 3.5. That's not a problem as VS2010 supports all versions of the .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is...  Since you're using NHibernate and EF, I'm guessing your doing some type of POCO implementation.  I've seen some stuff on the web about implementing POCO with NHibernate and EF where the base classes you define implement the IEntityWithRelationships interface.  If that's the case it would explain it.

Comment: Yes, but the base classes of my NHibernate entities have nothing to do with EF...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that one of your classes has the same name as a EF-class? Then it might be VS that is generating Code to apply the interface `IEntityWithRelationships` to your class to simulate POCO mapping of the classes.

> To use POCO entities with a data model, the name of the entity type must be the same as the custom data class, and each property of the entity type must map to a public property of the custom data class. The names of the types and each of the mapped properties must be equivalent.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5, i.e. EF 1. As far as I know, POCO entities where not supported in that version.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a library which has a public method or property that either returns a 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships' or takes one as a parameter. Regardless of it you are actually using the method, because it is public your code has to be able to determine the method signatures of all of the methods in the library you're referencing. If the method was internal you wouldn't see the issue.

Comment: As he states, that is not correct.

Only ones you create a reference to an object implementing or inheriting from a class or interface must you have the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried just double clicking on the error? That will usually go to the actual point of using the unknown type(either a return value/property or inheritance/implementation).

If that didn't work then it must be in compiler magic code(possibly for EF as people have pointed out, or somewhere else). In that case my suggestion would be to add the reference to your test assembly. Then open it in Reflector and look through the compiled MSIL. Since it is giving you a specific interface you could even just go to that interface and ask Reflector for where it is referenced to see where it is in your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be unrelated, but I had similar errors a while ago, I cleared out the ASP.NET assembly cache folder and it fixed my problem.

the folder is here

```
{windows folder}\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

and it was holding an old version of my assembly